# multiple query in one php file , i tried to write the code but i am not getting it done

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I want to execute mysql_qry1 also , how should i do it , till now my code is working fine but i want to execute the second query also(mysql_qry1) , please help.

```
<?php
require "conn.php";
$status=1;
$user_name = $_POST["user"];
$user_pass = $_POST["pass"];
$mysql_qry = "select * from tbl_client where username like '$user_name' and password like '$user_pass'";
$mysql_qry1 = "insert into login_status (username, status) values ('$user_name','$status)";
$result = mysqli_query($conn , $mysql_qry);
if(mysqli_num_rows($result)==1) {
echo "login success , Hello";
}
else {
echo "login failed";
}
$conn->close();

?>
```

Comment: Why have you used like for user name and password comparison? And why have you written select and insert query in one statement? It seems weird.

Comment: basically its a login username , so if the user gets the correct username and password then i want to put some values like his username and status variable in a diffrent table

Comment: @HemantVyas Your query seems to be missing ') in the end of insert statement.

Comment: @Prashanth yeah sry let me check

Answer (score 1):

Your SQL is one of most dangerous, please try to re-write:

```
//$mysql_qry = "select * from tbl_client where username like '$user_name' and password like '$user_pass'";
```

I m not sure what is in our conn.php, here is one of the example to update (PDO):

```
$sql = 'select 1 from tbl_client where username = :user and password = :pass';
$sth = $dbL->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute(':user' => $user_name, ':pass' => $user_pass);
$row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
if ($row[0]) {
    echo 'Login OK';
} else {
    echo 'Login Failed';
}

$sql = 'insert into login_status (username, status) values (:user, :status)';
$sth = $dbL->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute(':user' => $user_name, ':status' => $status);
```

OK, so your conn.php is using mysqli_ . Please refer to this page for help:
http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

And change above answer to:

```
$sql = 'select 1 from tbl_client where username = ? and password = ?';
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, $sql);
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'ss', $user_name, $user_pass);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
$row = mysqli_stmt_fetch();
if ($row[0]) {
    echo 'Login OK';
} else {
    echo 'Login Failed';
}
```

I have not used mysqli before, so not quite familiar, even php.net is hard to find out some docs about it. Please google howto use: mysqli_stmt_fetch() and replace it with proper code

Why not update your conn.php to use PDO? (be careful, you might need to update all your other pages as well which are calling this file):

```
// conn.php
$pdo = 'mysql:host=' . $server_name . ';dbname=' . $db_name;
$dbL = new PDO($pdo, $mysql_username, $mysql_password);
```

Comment: in my conn.php , it is just the database connection. "
"<?php
$db_name= "xxx";
$mysql_username ="xxx";
$mysql_password = "xxx";
$server_name= "xxxx";
$conn = mysqli_connect($server_name ,$mysql_username , $mysql_password ,$db_name);

?>"

Do i need to change any thing here to work the things ?

Comment: Hello the code is not working , i want to do the things which are in comments(in my code) , is PDO::FETCH_NUM working ?

Comment: 5-10 pages are calling this conn.php , so i need to stick with msqli if there is a way in which using msqli we can do my task that would be great , else i need to stick with PDO :(

Comment: 10 pages is nothing. PDO is easier.

Comment: ok can work with that thanks will call for help if i get stuck